JupyterLab not reading ipython_kernel_config.py
I have been using Jupyter and Jupyterlab, with Python, for many users, using Anaconda to install everything. With Anaconda's change in licensing policy, I am trying to move away from Anaconda and using just conda with the conda-forge channel.  One thing that used to work, but I can't get to work now is the ipython_kernel_config.py, located in ~/.ipython/profile-default. With the Anaconda installation, this file is loaded automatically when a Jupyter notebook is started with a Python kernel. But, it isn't with my new, more minimal, installation. The only thing that I can think of is that there is something that is included in the Anaconda full install that missing and necessary in my new installation.
This is what I have installed now:
numpy
scipy
matplotlib
jupyterlab
notebook
uncertainties

The specific thing that I want to be able to do from ipython_kernel_config.py is this command:
c.IPKernelApp.pylab = "inline"

This automatically loads numpy and matplotlib.pyplot and sets up inline plotting. I can do these things manually, obviously, but they are convenient and it would be nice to have this functionality.
